# how can i make my UIImage autoSizing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In a area of my UIView, i want display a UIImage, but the width and height of it are not determinate. I want the UIImage can be autosize to a determinate size.
thanks!!

Comment: you want to show image for entire view?

Comment: just a little part of UIView. i want show the whole content of UIImage but with a smaller size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem. If you want to adjust image view height and width according to view so use some thing like this,

```
float height=yourView.height;
float width=yourView.Width;

CGRect imageFrame=yourImageView.view.frame;

//set these values according to you
imageFrame.size.height=height-50;
imageFrame.size.width=width-50;

imageFrame.origin.x=20;
imageFrame.origin.y=40;

yourImageView.view.frame=imageFrame;
```